# Magento sample data installation help

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, sample-data

I followed the instructions and tried to install the sample data but the frontend looks something like this[image: Frontend pic]

I'm new to magento and don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [guide on how to install it](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/how-to-install-sample-data-for-magento/)

Main thing that you should know that you need to extract magento sample data (.sql file and media folder) then put media folder into your magento installation and import .sql file into your empty database **before** you will run Magento installation wizard, otherwise you won't be able to successfully install sample data

Also check your theme configuration [see here](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/enabling-your-new-theme-magento)